# Does it make sense to provide only const iterators for a container?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have a container similar to next one:

```
class MySpecialContainer
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<InternalType, Type1, Type2>> _vec;
};
```

where `Type1` and `Type2` are usable outside the container and `InternalType` is used only inside the container. To iterate through the elements from outside I'm using a member function similar to next one:

```
void MySpecialContainer::iterate(std::function<void(const Type1&, const Type2&)> fun)
{
    for(auto& it : _vec)
    {
        fun(std::get<1>(it), std::get<2>(it));
    }
}
```

As you can see this approach has several limitations, like not being able to iterate on a subrange or not being able to use non mutating `std::algorithms`.

Considering `MySpecialContainer` elements are non mutable from outside from logical considerations does it make sense to provide only `const_iterator` for it?

If the answer if yes for the first question, is it better to...?

1. separate `_vec` into 2 containers, one for `InternalType` and one for `std::pair<Type1, Type2>`, keep them synchronized and just return `const_iterator` for second vector
2. keep the vector as it is now and make a custom iterator that exposes only `const Type1` and `const Type2`

Comment: Does it make sense to have a proper class instead of the `tuple` (and so you may expose `Type1`, `Type2` via accessor).

Comment: @Jarod42 Very nice solution for second question! Thanks!

Comment: @Felics For your first question, yes, providing a const iterator for the encapsulated vector is the easiest solution when you want to prevent modification from outside the class. As a bonus by allowing only the const-iterator to be returned you are communicating your intentions for the member as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just exposing const iterators is fine.  There is even precedence in the standard for this, as `std::set` effectively does this.  Technically, `iterator` and `const_iterator` can be different types, but you are not allowed to modify the elements through either type of iterator, as that could break the invariants for `set`.

Comment: This is the answer to the first question, for the answer to the second questions please check Maxim Yegorushkin's answer.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to expose iterators that give access to certain fields only of your elements, e.g.:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

struct Type1 {};
struct Type2 {};
struct InternalType {};

class MySpecialContainer
{
    typedef std::vector<std::tuple<InternalType, Type1, Type2>> Vec;
    Vec _vec;

    struct Extractor
    {
        std::tuple<Type1&, Type2&> operator()(Vec::value_type& t) const {
            return std::tie(std::get<1>(t), std::get<2>(t));
        }

        std::tuple<Type1 const&, Type2 const&> operator()(Vec::value_type const& t) const {
            return std::tie(std::get<1>(t), std::get<2>(t));
        }
    };

public:
    typedef boost::transform_iterator<Extractor, Vec::iterator> iterator;
    typedef boost::transform_iterator<Extractor, Vec::const_iterator> const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return iterator{_vec.begin()}; }
    iterator end() { return iterator{_vec.end()}; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator{_vec.begin()}; }
    const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator{_vec.end()}; }
};

int main() {
    MySpecialContainer c;
    for(auto x : c) {
    }
}
```

Note that through non-const iterators you can still update the exposed values because the trasform iterator returns a tuple of references.

Comment: Is there a equivalent of `boost::transform_iterator` in the standard library?

Comment: @Felics Nope, the standard library is pretty bare-bones. This is why boost exists... You could derive `std::vector::iterator` and override `operator*` and `operator->` to do the transformation.

Comment: Thanks! I will upvote your answer as it a very interesting approach on how to provide iterators. I won't accept it as it doesn't answer my question about providing only `const_iterator`

Comment: @Felics Well, you could omit the non-const version of begin/end. They are exposed here to demonstrate that it is possible to provide modifiable views on some members of your elements.